# TestCafe CLI doesn't properly logout of application with auth0

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I have a web application that implemented auth0.  I can successfully login.  The issue I have, is if I click out 'Sign-out', TestCafe running in CLI never signs the user out.  The page is just immediately refreshed.  When performing the same behavior within TestCafe **Studio**, everything behaves correctly - user is brought back to the original landing page and the auth0 login overlay is populated.

Is this an issue specifically with TestCafe CLI?  Or something within my Web App?

Comment: I recommend that you re-submit your inquiry on StackOverflow where the TestCafe community may answer your question:
[https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=testcafe](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=testcafe)

Comment: Thanks - I asked over there